# Eclipse/STS: proxy auto configuration in STS.ini

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Having an issue regarding the following Eclipse Kepler/STS version:

```
Version: 3.5.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 201405030657
Platform: Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2)
```

I can't add the proxy configuration  like i did in old versions using the following added lines in STS.ini:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors= org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
-Dhttp.ProxyPort=XXXX
-Dhttp.ProxyHost=XXXX
```

The config must not be set manually but launched automatically with STS bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I had misunderstood the location of proxy settings in STS.ini: must be placed after the `-vmargs` this way:

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors= org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
-Dhttp.ProxyPort=XXXX
-Dhttp.ProxyHost=XXXX
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
-Xmn128m
-Xms256m
-Xmx768m
-Xss4m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
-XX:CompileThreshold=1000
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to configure the proxy settings in Eclipse/STS via the preferences dialog. Once that is done, it will persisted and used after every restart. Or do you have to set those proxies via the sts.ini file?

Comment: i'm making an STS bundle for distributing to others developers, then i need to pass it over STS.ini